# Calculating download time with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hey guys am new to javascript actually..i am trying to find the download time of a file.So i have dind the size of the file and divided it with the current time ..but its not giving me the correct result.

The code i have tried

```
function get_filesize(url, callback) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("HEAD", url, true); // Notice "HEAD" instead of "GET",
                             //  to get only the header
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
        callback(parseInt(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")));
    }
};
xhr.send();
}




get_filesize("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Google_web_search.png", function(size) {

var estimatedtime = (new Date().getTime())/size;
console.log(estimatedtime);

});
```

when i done do this i get output as `32245538.389347337`.

What am expecting is to get the time in `hh:mm:ss` in the console.

How can i acheive this ??..Any help would be great Thanks

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to calculate here? Download speed? Or simply download time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you calculate the value, convert it to date like below (of course, change the hardcoded value to `estimatedtime`):

```js
var time = new Date(32245538.389347337);
alert(time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes() + ":" + time.getSeconds());
```

Comment: when I REplaced the image file with aq music file i got alert like nan nan nan

Comment: i also get error like No 'content-length' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
babe.html:21 NaN:NaN:NaN

Comment: It is nothing with the code. You get nan:nan:nan because you can't initialize the date due to missing content-length. What is the response header from the server? If it is your own server, what server that you using. You need to check why the server did not return the content-length?

Comment: i fixed the issue .but the time i am getting is completely wrong i get 57 minute estimate time for a single picture which is false

Comment: My code above just show you how to convert from a number to date time as per question: how to get hh:mm:ss. Your estimated time `var estimatedtime = (new Date().getTime())/size;` is current time divided by size which is incorrent. Estimated time should be total size / transfer rate (bytes per seconds).

Comment: ..can you tell me how can i get transfer rate with js ??

Comment: Hmmm.. This is a good question, you can't get the transfer rate if you did not perform a download. However, you can refer [Detect connection speed](http://ditio.net/2008/08/06/detect-connection-speed-with-javascript/), [algorithm to estimate download time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779600/how-to-estimate-download-time-remaining-accurately). You can try google to find more.

Comment: Chond thanx ..:) can you tell me how the timer can be moved i have tried settimeout but it isnt working

Comment: You want the function to be execute once or at specific interval? So far what you had tried? I can't advise if you just said it is not working. Btw, you can refer [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479824/make-the-clock-decrement to see what i have tried