# Make the clock decrement

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am trying to get an expected download time with an ajax script..It just works fine ..I get the expected time in the format `hh:mm:ss`.But the clock isnt moving The code i have tried

```
function get_filesize(url, callback) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("HEAD", url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
        callback(parseInt(xhr.getResponseHeader(
            "Content-Length")));
    }
};

xhr.send();

}


get_filesize(
"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Google_web_search.png",
function(size) {
    var estimatedtime = (new Date().getTime()) / size;
    var time = new Date(estimatedtime);
    var c = setTimeout(function() {
        time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes() + ":" +
            time.getSeconds()
    }, 500);

    console.log(c);

});
```

When i try this code i get an output like `1`.

## What i need as my output

Suppose the output i got is `00:57:12` i need to decrement the time as a timer like `00:57:11` ans so on.

I havnt no idea on how to try this ..i have tried `setTimeout` But it didnt helped me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..Thanx

Comment: time.getSeconds() - 1 ???

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal tried but didnt worked

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how you calculate your estimated time? You get the current time and divide it by the file size? Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Regardless the logic of how you get the estimated time, just want to point out that if you using setTimeout, it only will run once after you trigger the get_filesize function. If you want the timer to keep decreasing, you should use setInterval as per suggested by @ykc which it will run on every x milliseconds. Besides that, I found that you never update your time variable. The code in setTimeout will run but it will keep show the same value.

Comment: @JoeyChong thanx man .can you tell me how can i get the transfer rate if an item is downloading ??..is transfer rate == bandwidth of my connection at download time ??

Comment: @JoeyChong i have searched all over but i couldnt find it ??..is the transfer rate equals to my bandwidth speed at time of download ?

Comment: @JoeyChong ????????????????????????????

Comment: I thought I had give you some references on your previous post? Anyways, you also can refer to this [detect internet speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try setInterval instead of setTimeout :

```
setInterval(function() {
   var c = time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes() + ":" +
        time.getSeconds();
   console.log(c);
}, 500);
```

**Edit :** I updated the code above

Comment: i get the same output which is 1 when i run this code

Comment: can you tell me how can i decrease the hour,minute and seconds

Comment: To decrease you should declare the c variable outside the scope of the function in the setInterval, and initialize it with the time you want in seconds, then in the setInterval, you set c = c - 1; (or c--; or c -= 1;) and you can display the result in your time format (see this link :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss)