# How to test user network speed from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating Connection/Download Speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370641/calculating-connection-download-speed)

I put data on 3 servers for app usage. I want to users load data from the fastest server base on their network connection. So I need to test user's network connection speed to my server. Is there any way to test user network speed from iPhone?

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370641/calculating-connection-download-speed I hope it helps, I tried personally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution and it works fine.

I put a small static file, for example https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png, on every server, then download the file from every server and calculate time spent ([Calculating Connection/Download Speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370641/calculating-connection-download-speed) is a good way to calculate speed, thanks to @Antonio MG), then save the fastest server host with `NSUserDefaults`. Before the app load data from server, replace request url host with the fastest host.

When app launched or `applicationWillEnterForeground:`, perform the network speed test. Now, every time at app load data is using the fastest server that just calculated.

Hope this can help those who need it.